# Cannot use BeautifulSoup's get_text() function on a span tag, returns an attribute error

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

for my computer sciences course I am trying to write a web scraper python script that finds all of the games on the playstation store that are on sale using python and beautiful soup. Right now, im just trying to get the program to list all of the games on the first page, their prices and their sale percentage (if there is one). However, for all of the games that are on sale, the terminal returns an attribute error: 'nontype' object has no attribute 'get_text'. Here is my code:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

my_url = 'https://store.playstation.com/en-ca/category/85448d87-aa7b-4318-9997-7d25f4d275a4/1'

uClient = uReq(my_url)
page_html = uClient.read()
uClient.close()

page_soup = soup(page_html, "html.parser")
containers = page_soup.find_all("section",{"class":"ems-sdk-product-tile__details"})



for container in containers: 

   title = container.span.get_text() 

   salePercentContainer = container.find("span",{"class":"psw-body-2 discount-badge discount-badge-- 
   undefined"})
   salePercent = salePercentContainer.get_text()
   if salePercent is None:
      salePercent = 'none'


priceContainer = container.strike
price = priceContainer#.text
if price is None:
    Rprice = container.find_all("span",{"class":"price"})
    price = Rprice[0].text

print("title: " + title)
print("sale percent: " + str(salePercent))
print("price: " + str(price))
```

Comment: Without more detail all I can tell you for sure is that one of the objects you are calling `.get_text()` with isn't what you think it is. It's effectively null (or a NoneType in python). I would recommend watching `container`, `salePercentContainer`, etc. One of them isn't resolving to anything. It's likely salePercentContainer and you'll probably want to check if it is null before trying to do `get_text`

Comment: `nontype` means `None` and it means it couldn't find element on page - so you try to do  `None.get_text()`

Comment: probably page uses JavaScript to add elements but `BeatifulSoup`/`requests` can't run JavaScript. You may need [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) to control real web browser which can run JavaScript. BTW: turn off JavaScript in web browser and load page again to see what Beautifulsoup can get from server.

Comment: if pages works without JavaScript then you should check what you get in `page_html` - ie. use `print()` or save in file and open in web browser. Maybe server recognized that you use script and it send HTML with warning for bots or with Captcha.

Comment: @DoloMike turns out salePercentContainer is null, thank you.

Comment: @JoeC. happy to help!

Answer (score 0):

Put in a `try:except`, so it doesn't fail for `elements` which don't have what you are looking for.

```
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

my_url = 'https://store.playstation.com/en-ca/category/85448d87-aa7b-4318-9997-7d25f4d275a4/1'

uClient = uReq(my_url)
page_html = uClient.read()
uClient.close()

page_soup = soup(page_html, "html.parser")
containers = page_soup.find_all("section",{"class":"ems-sdk-product-tile__details"})



for container in containers:
    try:
        title = container.span.get_text()
        print(title)

        salePercentContainer = container.find("span",{"class":"psw-body-2 discount-badge discount-badge--undefined"})
        salePercent = salePercentContainer.get_text()
        print(salePercent)
        if salePercent is None:
            salePercent = 'none'
     except Exception as e:
        pass

priceContainer = container.strike
print(priceContainer)
price = priceContainer  # .text
if price is None:
    Rprice = container.find_all("span", {"class": "price"})
    price = Rprice[0].text
    print(price)

print("title: " + title)
print("sale percent: " + str(salePercent))
print("price: " + str(price))
```

Output:-

```
Just Cause 4
Rocket Arena
Vigor
Rocket League®
Fortnite
Days Gone
-50%
God of War
Genshin Impact
Mortal Kombat X
Rogue Company
Crash Bandicoot™ N. Sane Trilogy
eFootball PES 2021 LITE
Apex Legends™
Fallout 4
-70%
Stranded Deep
MONSTER HUNTER: WORLD™
RESIDENT EVIL 7 biohazard
-50%
The Last Guardian
Bloodborne™
Horizon Zero Dawn: Complete Edition
Persona 5
Battlefield™ 1
NHL® 21
-52%
Wreckfest
-30%
The Last Of Us™ Remastered 
Until Dawn
inFAMOUS Second Son
Detroit: Become Human
Red Dead Online
SHAREfactory™
Brawlhalla
Hyper Scape
Rec Room
Bless Unleashed
RACING BROS
F1 2020
-50%
NBA 2K21
-50%
Spellbreak
SMITE
Grand Theft Auto V
Injustice™ 2
-75%
UFC® 4
-50%
SPIDER-MAN: FAR FROM HOME VIRTUAL REALITY EXPERIENCE
Dead Island Definitive Edition
MX vs ATV All Out
Hello Neighbor
NARUTO TO BORUTO: SHINOBI STRIKER
Tomb Raider: Definitive Edition
None
$26.99
title: Tomb Raider: Definitive Edition
sale percent: -50%
price: $26.99
```

Answer (score 0):

The data is within a json format in the html source. You can pull that out and parse that as well.

Simply filter the dataframe to show what you want.

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
import json
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

rows = []
for page in range(1,11):
    url = 'https://store.playstation.com/en-ca/category/85448d87-aa7b-4318-9997-7d25f4d275a4/%s' %page
    response = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
    
    jsonStr = soup.find_all('script',{'type':'application/json'})[2].text
    jsonData = json.loads(jsonStr)
    
    state = jsonData['props']['apolloState']
    
    
    print ('Page: %s' %page)
    for k, v in state.items():
        if 'Product:' in k and '.price' in k:
            skuId = k.split('.price')[0][1:]
            title = jsonData['props']['apolloState'][skuId]['name']
            v.update({'title':title})
            rows.append(v)
        
df = pd.DataFrame(rows)
```

**Output:**

```
print (df)
    basePrice discountedPrice  ... __typename                         title
0       $0.00        Included  ...   SkuPrice                  Just Cause 4
1       $6.99           $6.99  ...   SkuPrice                  Rocket Arena
2        Free            Free  ...   SkuPrice                         Vigor
3        Free            Free  ...   SkuPrice                Rocket League®
4        Free            Free  ...   SkuPrice                      Fortnite
..        ...             ...  ...        ...                           ...
472    $39.99           $9.99  ...   SkuPrice  MX vs. ATV Supercross Encore
473    $29.99          $29.99  ...   SkuPrice      ASTRO BOT Rescue Mission
474    $33.49          $33.49  ...   SkuPrice                    Descenders
475    $54.99          $21.99  ...   SkuPrice                    Fallout 76
476    $24.99          $24.99  ...   SkuPrice         LEGO® Jurassic World™

[477 rows x 10 columns]
```

**Show discounted:**

```
discounted_df = df[~df['discountText'].isnull()]
```

**Output:**

```
print(discounted_df.head(5).to_string())
   basePrice discountedPrice discountText  isFree  isExclusive               serviceBranding                  upsellServiceBranding    upsellText __typename                      title
5     $49.99          $24.99         -50%   False        False  {'type': 'json', 'json': []}   {'type': 'json', 'json': ['PS_NOW']}      Included   SkuPrice                  Days Gone
13    $39.99          $11.99         -70%   False        False  {'type': 'json', 'json': []}                                   None          None   SkuPrice                  Fallout 4
16    $26.99          $13.49         -50%   False        False  {'type': 'json', 'json': []}                                   None          None   SkuPrice  RESIDENT EVIL 7 biohazard
22    $79.99          $38.39         -52%   False        False  {'type': 'json', 'json': []}                                   None          None   SkuPrice                    NHL® 21
23    $39.99          $27.99         -30%   False        False  {'type': 'json', 'json': []}  {'type': 'json', 'json': ['PS_PLUS']}  Save 5% more   SkuPrice                  Wreckfest
```